# Can I work in Wallonia and live in Brussels?

Tags: belgium

I am a non-EU student at a German university and I will be doing an internship in a company in Wallonia (Belgium).
Can I look for accommodation anywhere in Belgium (for example, Brussels) or do I need to live in the same region I'll be working in?

Answer (score 2):

There are no border checks within Belgium. Many people working in Brussels live in Wallonia or Flanders, because it is cheaper.

Your employer may ask you to find a place near, to avoid delays in travel, but not for legal reasons.